# PHP mail(); not sending simple mail throug ssmtp

Tags: php, linux, nginx, ssmtp

actually if I run the mail function in the php console (php -a) it works, but if i do it on a php script and I execute it from chrome it doesnt work.

```
<?php
   mail('test@gmail.com', 'Subject', 'Hello!');
?>
```

Im using Nginx with PHP-FPM and ssmtp SMTP server.

Note: Investigating, the problem is on Nginx or FPM, when i run the script from terminal it works.

Thanks!

Comment: done any debugging? check return values from mail()? check your smtp server's logs?  check your web server's error log to see if many there's a security system blocking mail activity? there is absolutely no way to answer your question without more details.

Comment: mail() return false.. I dont see any error in smtp server and nginx logs.

Comment: false means that the mail can't even leave php to get to your server's local smtp engine.

Comment: What can i do to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: What does `phpinfo()` say about your mail settings?

Comment: The emails and path's are good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using php-fpm in chrooted mode?

If so chances are that a lot of system mail() requirements aren't available to your chrooted envirronment.

usually such chroot external programs problems can  be solved by creating a faxed filesystem in the chrooted path (devices, libraries). But for mail it's harder. The usual solution is not using the php mail call but using instead an smtp communication (with localhost for example). Some examples are listed [here](http://flexichat.net/chroot-php-fpm).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install PEAR and using the PEAR mail?